# AWS SNS For Mass Communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, communication, amazon-sns

This is a general architecture question so I hope it's valid enough to be a post.

I'm developing a Mass Communication application that will send out information in the form of email, SMS, text to voice phone calls to many people (hence the word mass or massive), and possibly HTTP calls to other applications. I've been using [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) as my prototype but recently I've been looking into some of the Amazon Web Services (AWS) to see if they could help my application out in any way.

In particular AWS Simple Notification Service (SNS) stood out because it's able to send email, SMS, and HTTP. I've been told though that AWS SNS is not designed to be a mass communication tool. What are some thoughts on whether or not AWS SNS can hold up to a mass communication application? I personally don't see why it couldn't be used for this purpose.

Comment: how many people do you need to send the message to?

Comment: Potentially a thousand or more. It depends on the particular situation.

Comment: I don't recommend sending email to end-users via SNS, you have no control over the email formatting or the big unsubscribe link that will fill half the email. SNS emails are more appropriate for sending alerts to sysadmins about internal AWS events.

Comment: @markB that's a very good example, thank you.

Comment: Your SNS topic could trigger a method over HTTP that initiates the mail sending using SES. So in short, use SNS to trigger the sending and not the actual sending.

Comment: @jbird that's an interesting idea. Why wouldn't the email that comes with SNS be enough though?

Comment: Like @MarkB said, email endpoints for SNS are more appropriate for one-off messages about system events. To use SNS you would have to subscribe each of the email addresses to the SNS topic and that would be time consuming. With SES you could have the address list stored in a text file that is read from disk when SNS triggers the HTTP endpoint.

Comment: @jbird ah I see, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: We recently used it to send push notifications to iOS and Android apps. These were all individualised messages i.e. not the same message going to thousands of users. In our testing (using a fairly large EC2 instance to get info from AWS DDB), we have been able to send thousands of notifications in a matter of minutes. When extrapolated, those stats can reach upto a million notifications in an hour.

Answer (score 0):

The Service to look at is Pinpoint for this type of use case. Then you can use AWS Step Functions to build a workflow. For example, assume you work at a school and you need to alert parents when a student skips school. Do you send an email, do you phone the parents, or do you send a text message?

Using AWS, you can create a workflow that can use all of these channels. The more channels you use, the better chance you reach your intended audience, which is this use case is the parents.

[image]

This AWS tutorial will be posted here once done.